# the Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

this code below is for the quantity. The price of the product times the quantity then you get the total

```
If CheckedListBox1.Text = "1" Then
        TextBox5.Text = 1
        TextBox4.Text = TextBox5.Text * TextBox4.Text<<<<<<  This part keeps saying "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid". Please help!
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckedListBox1.Text = "2" Then
        TextBox5.Text = 2
        TextBox4.Text = TextBox4.Text * TextBox5.Text
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckedListBox1.Text = "3" Then
        TextBox5.Text = 3
        TextBox4.Text = TextBox5.Text * TextBox4.Text
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckedListBox1.Text = "4" Then
        TextBox5.Text = 4
        TextBox4.Text = TextBox5.Text * TextBox4.Text
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Comment: 1.  Turn on Option Strict  2. Fix Errors  3. Profit!  TextBoxes hold text/strings not numbers.  You cant do meaningful math with them.  What is the answer to `"Apple" * "Cat"` ?

Comment: It looks to me like textbox4 has no text in it. In `Conversion from string "" ` the `""` bit is the string it's trying to convert to a double value.  And it doesn't know how to. You might think it'd translate to `0` but it won't.

Comment: `What is the answer to "Apple" * "Cat"` ***Capple*** I would assume :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code (And all others like it in your various if statements)

```
TextBox4.Text = TextBox5.Text * TextBox4.Text
```

To this

```
TextBox4.Text = (CDbl(TextBox5.Text) * CDbl(TextBox4.Text)).ToString()
```

This way your text is being casted to a `double` before being operated on and then once your mathematical operation is complete the result is converted back to text via the `.ToString()` function

**Note:** If you use text boxes for user input numerical data you are also going to have to handle for non-numerical input and disallow the user from typing anything but numbers and decimal points. (This includes handling for empty strings as noted by @Jeroen) I would recommend you consider using a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead

Comment: That answer is incorrect. Consider `MsgBox(CDbl("") * CDbl(4).ToString())` still throws the same runtime error as the OP complained about. Empty strings can't be converted to Dbl. Also, IMHO masked input boxes are much friendlier than NumericUpDown

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from previous answer, I would say this:

```
Dim dbl1, dbl2 As Double
If Double.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, dbl1) AndAlso Double.TryParse(TextBox5, dbl2) Then
    TextBox4.Text = dbl1 * dbl2
Else
    MsgBox("Danger, Will Robinson!")
End If
```

However, if you expect there to be a `double` you need to make sure the user enters a value that can correctly be converted. Doing it later on in the code, is just a quick fix for a problem that should have been caught long before you ever started writing code that performs maths...

Comment: it does show danger, wlll Robinson. It doesn't seem to work . Am still getting the same "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid". error message

Comment: It's working fine. The if statement  checks to see that both text boxes can be successfully converted to a double. One, or both cannot. That is why the MsgBox displays. So far so good. You get the error message because you are still not handling the error.   On which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: It works. The if statements does check but the quantity doesn't add to the sum like i would like . Instead when the program is rendered and i click on the quantity section it just displays the " danger, Will Robinson". Funny though lol

Comment: You are setting `TextBox5.Text` to a value of 1, that can be converted to a double. `TextBox4.Text` contains a value that `TryParse` can't convert. You need to check the value of Text4 before you go into this code.